# Teradata - Case - PARTITION

Tags: case, teradata, partition

i have the following query that brings for each party_id all  the business_party_id related, their monthly accumulated value for each BP and the rank for that value. there s a special business_party_id = 200 that when a given party_id has more than 1 related business_party and that business_party_ ranks 1 while being 200 then it shouldn t be considered and the rank 2 for that party_id should be the one considered as rank 1 and move the 200 to rank 2.

how can i do that?

here s my query

```
select party_id,
business_party_id, 
monthly_accum_event_amt,
Row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY  party_id ORDER BY  monthly_accum_event_amt  desc) orden

from (
    select * from P_DMT_VIEWS.BUSINESS_AGREEMENT_PAYROLL
    where LAST_DAY( payroll_dt) = '2018-05-31'
    and not business_payrroll_concept_val  in ('SUE004','SUE005','SUE00A')
    and monthly_event_qty<>0
    QUALIFY Row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY  business_party_id,party_id ORDER BY   monthly_event_qty desc  ) =1) a
```

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Can you add some example data plus expected result and more explanation?

Comment: the idea is the following, the table reflects salary payments made to individuals (party_id) from each employer (business_party). i need to determine a single employer for a given individual and the criteria is to leave the one who pays the most but when that employer has an id = 200 and the individual has more than 1 employer then the single employer i want to see is the one ranking 2

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding, but you can use a case statement in your `order by` clause.